# Регулярное выражение в Google Forms

Tags: регулярные-выражения, google-forms

Не могу до конца понять регулярные выражение для Гугл форм.

Нужно сделать проверку на ввод в текстовое поле в виде ПК ХХ+ХХ,ХХ где все Х целые числа.

Такое возможно?

Comment: Это там, где выбираешь *Advanced Settings* -> *Data validation* -> *Regular Expression*? Выбери `matches` и напиши `ПК [0-9]{2}\+[0-9]{2},[0-9]{2}`.

Answer (score 2):

В **Advanced Settings** -> **Data validation** -> **Regular Expression** нужно выбрать `matches` и вписать

```
ПК [0-9]{2}\+[0-9]{2},[0-9]{2}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проверка в работе:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, так:

```
^ПК \d\d\+\d\d,\d\d$
```

Answer (score 0):

В форме ставлю "совпадает" и вот так :ПК \d++\d+,\d{2}. С количеством цифр после каждого составляющего еще разбираюсь.

Comment: Ваш ответ не соответствует заданному вопросу. Даже сомневаюсь куда минус ставить: вопросу или ответу.